# ASP.Net MultiView & JQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, asp.net, multiview

I have a jQuery accordion running inside an ASP.Net MultiView.

It works fine if placed on the first view, however when changing to another view with the accordion on it fails to work.

Looking in Firebug the code is all there, the styles etc... even the hover over works. Just no accordion behavior when clicking headings.

What am I doing wrong.

Only thing i can think of is to use the ASP.Net Accordion Ajax control, however that would make me sad.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - any detailed solution / code samples that solved the issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is update panel or ajax request, when you change the step jquery bindings are lost. You can use `endRequest` event to rebind the accordion.

more details about `endRequest` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx

Comment: Hello there, could you elaborate a little more? I have posted a similar issue with my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398607/jquery-accortion-aspmultiview-c-sharp