# jQuery Accordion + ASP:MultiView

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

My issue is similar to the one asked here, but the solution out there was not simple enough for me to comprehend / requesting more elaboration and/or code samples:

[ASP.Net MultiView & JQuery Accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908865/asp-net-multiview-jquery-accordion)

I have a jQuery UI accordion initialized on base.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var icons = {
                header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
                headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
            };

            $("#accordion1").accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                icons: icons,
                event: "mouseover"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Then in my accordion DIV, I call several user controls, one for each accordion section:

```
<div id="accordion1">
        <DT:TrainerCost ID="dtTrainerCost" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        <DT:TrainerAvailability ID="dtTrainerAvailability" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        <DT:ProfessionalInfo ID="dtProfessionalInfo" runat="server" />
</div>
```

These controls have in them an ASP:MultiView with two indexes 0 and 1. They default to 0. There's a button in Index0 which if clicked, launches View1.

When I display the default Index0 (on page load) everything with the accordion works well. But on clicking the button that triggers View1, I lose the jQuery accordion functionality... as per the other post, seems like jQuery bindings are being broken when the multi-view switches?

Comment: your controls are probably causing a postback , therefore refreshing the page , therefore refreshing the accordian

Comment: "But on clicking the button that triggers View1" 
you can taking care the "button click" make sure this click is ajax click otherwise it make a postback and your accordion and multiview goes on initial stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few days later, I was able to resolve my issue. These two articles gave it away:

https://siderite.dev/blog/including-external-javascript-on-async.html

http://forums.asp.net/t/1348484.aspx/1/10?error+in+MicrosoftAjax+js+Cannot+read+property+_notified+of+null

Bottomline was browser issues with ASP.Net AJAX.

Comment: Please be more specific about the nature of the browser issues.